# Looking at building an app using Laravel and Ionic Framework - some initial questions

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, laravel-5.1

I'm currently building a web app using Laravel 5.1 and would like to start creating a native application so that my users can use their phones. I have decided that using the Ionic Framework is likely the best approach for the app and just have a few questions on marrying the two together.

I've got routes in Laravel that looks like this example:

`app.dev/geckos` - This is a `GET` request.

Which takes the currently authenticated user, uses their ID and fetches all geckos that match their user ID. It does return a blade view however.

I assume that when working with something like Ionic, the `GET` request would need to return `JSON` instead on order to loop through properly?

Is there a way that I can alter my controller to serve `JSON` based on if the route was something like this instead:

`app.dev/api/v1/geckos`

Both routes would use the `GeckoController@index` method, ideally I just don't want to repeat the code.

I'm *fairly* new to Laravel and *very* new to Ionic. So if I'm over complicating this theory please let me know.

Any information is appreciated on this,

Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution which I used is to have 1. application in Laravel, which is a RESTful JSON API. Then you would have 2. Web app (in AngularJS) and 3. Mobile app in Ionic (which is based on AngularJS).

So you will create two separate applications, mobile and web, which both communicate with the same JSON API. The web would be a single-page AngularJS application, so that way you can reuse all the Angular services which communicate with the API, maybe even some controllers between your mobile Ionic and Web application.

You will save some time when creating two separate responses for mobile/web application, since you would create only one: JSON response. AngularJS will take care of rendering in both applications, that way you won't have to create separate templates for web applications in Blade, instead make all the rendering using Angular in both applications. There will be some nuances in rendering of the same content in Web and Mobile app, but it would only require creating separate js directives/css styles/html templates for both applications, using Blade you wouldn't be able to reuse any view related code between applications. Also you will be able to use the same Authentication method for both applications.

To sum up, this solution should be cleaner then your solution because you will be able to reuse backend entirely between the applications, reuse a lot of fronted stuff (like input validation code, services, filters,..), reuse Authentication and introduce looser coupling and have much clearer structure then the ugly response type switch in controllers.

**EDIT:**
So this can be a rough example of the structure of such project:

```
1. API - REST in Laravel, returning JSON
   -Controllers
       -Session // actions CREATE, DELETE
       -User    // actions CREATE, VIEW, UPDATE, DELETE..
       -Gecko

2. JS application - Angular App, for both mobile and web app
    -common //controllers, services, filters - most of the frontend logic which reusable between both applications
       -controllers.js
       -services.js
       -filters.js
    -mobile //this part can be hosted on some server or part of the mobile application
       -app.js //separate configs for mobile app
       -controllers.js //controllers only for mobile app
       -directives.js
    -web
       -app.js //separate configs for web app (links to HTML template URLS,...)
       -controllers.js //controllers only for web app
       -directives.js
       -services.js //or even services only for web app

3. WEB APP 
   -HTML Templates - bunch of static .HTML files
      -Home
          -Login
          -Register
      -Gecko
          -Gecko Views...
   -Some index file with layout template, which includes everything from js/common and js/web, entry point to your web application

4. MOBILE APP
   -www
      -index.html // must include everything from js/common and js/mobile
      -templates
         -Gecko
            -Gecko Views...
```

But the structure may vary significantly, depending on what part of mobile application you want to have hosted on web server and which should be available offline, or how you want to host it, how detailed the structure might be..

Comment: Sounds like a good approach. Do you have examples of your RESTful JSON API?

Comment: Sorry but it wasn't an open-source project so I won't be able to reveal those.  There was a "session" resource which when called with POST request with included login credentials, returned access token, which was then sent in all subsequent requests in HTTP header. Calling DELETE on it would log user out. So Authentication was done using access token, and the rest were just various REST resources.

Comment: I didn't mean exact copies haha, I meant as in dummy data to show the process

Comment: I have edited my answer a bit. I am not sure which part are you interested in and the example might vary depending on what exactly you want to achieve/how you want to achieve it. If you have more specific question I can try to answer it.

Comment: I have not included examples of respective files because that would be one looong post :)

Answer (score 1):

Doing this would be messy because your single controller action will be returning two totally different responses.

However if you go down this route, you could add an additional header to the request from the mobile app, and then check for this to switch the response.